# Smooth Camera Follow in Unity for 2D Platformer

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I've been scouring the internet for the past couple of hours trying to find a working solution to this. I've tried everything I could possibly think of: different types of functions, different types of updates, different smoothing times. Below is a video of how my game currently plays. I'm making a small platformer just for practice, and I want to get this camera problem out of the way! [Click here for video](https://youtu.be/4SdYmDzmR5o)

Here is my current code, but again, I've tried numerous other combinations, too. Thanks for all the help.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public Vector3 offset;
public float smoothTime = 0.3f;

private Vector3 velocity;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, target.position + offset, ref velocity, smoothTime);
}
}
```

EDIT:
I've tried a bunch of other suggestions, but nothing is still working. If this helps, I'm running Unity 2018.2.5f1 Personal 64 bit. I'm using a Razer Blade 15 2018.

Comment: Did you tried this topic's answers ? https://answers.unity.com/questions/29183/2d-camera-smooth-follow.html

Comment: Yup. Doesn't work :/. Thx anyway :D

Comment: Have you tried using linear interpolation?

Comment: Yup. For now, I'm working on gameplay. I'll come back to the camera when I need it. Hopefully I'll see it with fresh eyes and it'll start working ;P

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below. This piece of code works for me in my 3D game.

```
public float translationFactor = 20;

void LateUpdate(){
  if(transform.position != target.position) {
    transform.position += (target.position - transform.position) / translationFactor;           
  }
}
```

This is a direct quote about why you should use `LateUpdate()` when you are working with cameras, from Unity3D's [LateUpdate() documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html).

> LateUpdate is called after all Update functions have been called. This
>   is useful to order script execution. For example a follow camera
>   should always be implemented in LateUpdate because it tracks objects
>   that might have moved inside Update.

Also I've noticed that you use `Vector3` instead of `Vector2` in a **2D** game. I'm not experienced in 2D as much as I'm in 3D so I don't know if it will make any difference to replace `Vector3`s with `Vector2`s.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to give this a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting that same shaking. I think I'm going to start from scratch and see where that takes me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should work if you simply change the function name from `LateUpdate` to `Update`, if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still getting that shakiness.

Comment: Could you try `FixedUpdate`?

Comment: I've tried that too. It gets better, but then this happens. Check out this video. The other one still hasn't processed on Google Drive yet so I uploaded this one to YouTube. https://youtu.be/YitNRgMVweg There is just shaking that happens when the character is on the ground. Maybe I have to rewrite how I'm moving the character?

Comment: Maybe. Could you show the section of your script that moves the character?

Comment: Yeah. So I got the PlayerController and PlayerMovement. PlayerController handles input, and PlayerMovement actually moves the character. Click here for the code. https://docs.google.com/document/d/19Pbnwy6aovJY7kkWMU1lgq8aGi6K7C2VpMyBmLW_kY0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking your problem on your skeleton script. Your camera follows skeleton and you are thinking problem on camera
Try to move skeleton with `AddForce` instead of `transform.position`
Example

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayOneShot (voices[2]);
        birdSpeed.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        birdSpeed.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, birdUp));
    }
public void Buttons(int i){
    if (i == 0) {
        birds = 0.2f;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().gravityScale = 4;
        birdUp = 400;
        StartPanel.SetActive (false);
        GamePanel.SetActive (true);
        GameOverPanel.SetActive (false);
    }
```

In this code when i click to mouse bird up and you can adapt your code to this

Comment: Thanks for the option! Unfortunately, I'm still getting that same shaking. I think I'm going to start from scratch and see where that takes me.

Answer (score 0):

i know im late but for all of you asking this question i looked in to your problem and tested it in a game im working on, and i fixed your issue by changing void LateUpdate() to void FixedUpdate() here is the code! Hope i helped..

```
using UnityEngine;

    public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public float smoothTime = 0.3f;
    
    private Vector3 velocity;
    
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, target.position + offset, ref velocity, smoothTime);
    }
    }
```